# Error in "Loading schema for Unnamed Project" while integrating apollo ios client

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo, apollo-ios

I am trying to integrate apollo iOS client and after doing all steps I am getting the error while running build phase script.
so there are three errors in total. 
one is

1. Error initializing Apollo GraphQL project "Unnamed Project".
2. Error: Error in "Loading schema for Unnamed Project".
3. TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined at Object.error.

Note this accuring inside node_modules/@oclif.

`Error initializing Apollo GraphQL project "Unnamed Project": Error: Error in "Loading schema for Unnamed Project": TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes, I download the schema. actually the issue was in the schema file

Comment: You can find info how download schema [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/downloading-schema/). As said in previous comment this fixed the error

Comment: and this error is possible through if your **.graphql** file and **schema.json** are empty.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to check schema.json file inside your project, i have also faced same issue and same error but solved by adding schema.json file inside project directory

You can download it by below command

```
apollo schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:8080/graphql schema.json
```

Comment: This worked for me! 
Mac users must first install the apollo-cli via homebrew: brew install apollo-cli

Answer (score 1):

first you should add this command
npx apollo service:download --endpoint= schema.json

then run this command
npx apollo codegen:generate --localSchemaFile=graphql-schema.json --target=typescript --tagName=gql

Comment: Please describe why these command resolve the issue?

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. I had already linked the schema URL and it kept throwing errors for some reason. When I executed below lines, it worked like a charm for me. 
npx apollo service:download --endpoint= graphql-schema.json